# Is this "survey" type question desirable on the site?

Tags: discussion

By going through the late answer queue I found [a questions about favourite sounds](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/82/7176).

Although interesting to read, I don't see how this question fits the stackexchange format. I'm quite new to the Sound.SE page, so it might of course be that the general SE rules are applied differently here.

So my question is:
Are these type of questions desirable (it has 4 upvotes, so I suspect a yes) and if so, why?
Answers can't really be objective and I don't see how it helps future users.

I'm curious about this as then I would understand better when to flag a question here and how to help new users to ask "better" question.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question is a type of community oriented question that was common on Social Sound Design.  Thus far, the community has set a less stringent standard in terms of allowing for this kind of thing as long as it doesn't become a majority of questions or start detracting from the ability to get clear Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

Time will ultimately tell. The way to spot *truly* problematic questions is tons of answers that don't really contribute much. If all someone has to do to answer is leave a link, or just a few words, or a picture of their favorite bird, etc - then the question has some fundamental issues.

Questions starting more of a discussion should be *reasonably* narrowly-scoped, and invite (more like require) answers with a bit of depth to them.

So far, these have been pretty decent questions (well, for the most part). If we turn into more of a 'getting to know sound designers and engineers' than a 'lets talk about some hard problems in sound design and engineering' sort of place - then we're going to need to put the breaks on.

But, for that to happen, *this* community is going to need to experience those problems, and that might not ever happen. We (Stack Exchange) know what *can* go wrong with these, but we don't know *if* that's going to happen on any given site until it does.

So yes - be on the lookout for questions that are just going to get an absurd amount of not very useful or engaged answers - then vote to close them as too broad, as that's the definition of what we don't like about them. If that's not likely to happen - then answer the question if you can :)